# How does Gmail's "snooze" feature work when I move between timezones?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, if I snooze an email until some particular date and time (e.g. 1pm), then I physically go to another time zone and remain there, when does the notification occur? At 1pm in the new local time, or based on the time zone at the time it was snoozed?

Is the behavior the same in the web version and the mobile apps?